# Principle of filesystemwatcher component in .net

Tags: c#, .net

i wish to know the bsic principle of the filesystemwatcher component. How it will detect the events like created, deleted , renamed , changed?
On what basis it will detect the events ? Whether by file size or name or what ?

Comment: Why not create a simple console  app to log changes and test a few scenarios and see what happens.

Comment: I just want to know the principle of the component which was already in thr .net environment

Comment: The source code is available if you really want to dive in the inner workings. See https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/services/io/system/io/FileSystemWatcher.cs,a9eb0249dc928b09

Comment: Thanku very much @peter bons...

Answer (score 1):

It relies on a feature of NTFS called USN Journal. You can learn more about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USN_Journal).